# How to bridge Python and C++

Tags: c++, python, boost

I am frustrated, after all, by days of experimenting with Boost.Python, but achieved nothing.

I download and install and run bjam etc. as instructed. Further development will definitely be considered, but now I just want to start from something simple. However, the library just cannot even build a simple hello world example... The VS2012 keeps popping some errors like `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct`.

Anyway, I want to write some fundamental functions (such as add, multiply, etc) in C++, then call them from a Python script.

I'm sorry that I raised a very basic question. Can anyone show me a simple example? I think the code is fine by me, `the essence is how do you link and include the library in you project, and how do you setup the project properties.`

I would be extremely appreciate if someone can teach me. Thanks. :)

==========================================

EDIT:

I've posted something relavant before. Here is the linl: [How to solve __imp___Py_NoneStruct Error in Boost.Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963712/how-to-solve-imp-py-nonestruct-error-in-boost-python/18965627?noredirect=1#18965627)

I've posted all my linking and including operations there.

Many thanks. :)

Comment: What build environment are you using?

Comment: just link the python library

Comment: @mike Thanks for your reply. I am using Windows 7, Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express Version, Python 2.7, Boost 1.54. :)

Comment: @DieterLücking Do you mean `#include <Python.h>`? If so, I already did it, but only got an error `cannot open python27_d.lib`. Anyway, can you show me more detail? I think you have a very important point. Many thanks. :)

Comment: @NewLong please have a proper compiler/linker environment (paths, ...)

Comment: @NewLong: You need to rephrase your question. Give enough details saying, how you are compiling, and what are the linker errors you are facing.

Comment: @DieterLücking This is what I did:1.Add C:\local\boost_1_54\; C:\Python27\include; to C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories.

2.Add C:\local\boost_1_54\libs; C:\local\boost_1_54\lib64-msvc-11.0; C:Python27\libs; to Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.

3.Set "Not Using Precompiled Headers" to C/C++->Precompiled Header->Precompiled Header.

May I know what am I wrong? Many thanks. :)

Comment: @Abhijit Thanks for your advice, but I'm afraid that could cause moderators shut this post with 'Duplicated'. Can I ask you go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963712/how-to-solve-imp-py-nonestruct-error-in-boost-python/18965627?noredirect=1#18965627 to have a look at my other post? Many thanks. :)

Comment: @DieterLücking Thanks. I think you are right. So, can you point out my mistake? Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are linking all libraries in the correct version?

Boost.Python requires a compiled library from boost and linking to the correct python runtime library. If you compile in Debug mode, all linked libraries should be debug version, too.

Alternatives to boost would be [SWIG](http://swig.org/) or if you have a C-compatible interface [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) or [cffi](https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi).

Comment: I'm not sure if I've done right. I've raised a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963712/how-to-solve-imp-py-nonestruct-error-in-boost-python/18965627?noredirect=1#18965627, and I put all my linking operations there. Can you have a look? Many thanks. :)

Comment: @NewLong: I saw the other thread and saw you mentioned that you faced an issue `error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python27_d.lib'`. Did you solve the issue? if not, that is the first thing you need to. The suggested solution in your other question is correct.

Comment: @Abhijit No, it's another nightmare haunting me. Do you mean the correct answer is include python.h?

Comment: @NewLong: To get around your debug dll missing linking error, do a retail build or you have to build python to create a debug dll.

Comment: @Abhijit I knows very little about python, so can you explain more? Many thanks. :)

Comment: @NewLong: Do you know how to do a retail build in VS? I am not sure what exact problems you are facing and what you have done so far.

Comment: @Abhijit Sorry, I have no idea. Can you teach me a little? Thank you. :)

Comment: @NewLong: See my answer to the other question. I have given enough links to get you started

Comment: @Abhijit Thank you very much for your kindly help. I've followed your advice, but now I have a new error :'error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

There is native python library which is called 'ctypes'. [In here you can find some some examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think that calling from Python is not my first priority. I'd like to run hello world example from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html#python.quickstart first, then learn more about the library.